# Dynamically Change the path in fragments from controller UI5

Tags: sapui5

I have a fragment as below with path : myModel1>/1/TileCollection  but I want to make it dynamic from controller like myModel1>/n/TileCollection like n can be an 0 to 1000.

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout">
 <Page id="master22" showHeader="false" enableScrolling="true" >    
     <TileContainer
      id="container">
       tiles="{myModel1>/1/TileCollection}">   
      <StandardTile      
        icon="{myModel1>icon}"  
        number="{myModel1>number}"
        numberUnit="{myModel1>numberUnit}"
        title="{myModel1>title}"
        info="{myModel1>info}"
        infoState="{myModel1>infoState}" 
        press="handleTilePress"/>  
       </TileContainer>  
       </Page> 
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

JSON String :
When type key is 0 , I want different set of tiles and when it is 1 , different tiles....similarly goes on..

```
[{
        "type": "01",
        "typeKey": "0",
  "TileCollection" : [
    {
      "id-tile": "1AP",
      "icon" : "sap-icon://inbox",
      "number" : "899999",
      "title" : "Accounting Documents",
      "info" : "Overdue",
      "infoState" : "Error",
       "press" :  "sayAlert"
    },
    {
     "id-tile": "2AP",
      "type" : "sap-icon://Create",
       "number" : "57899",
      "title" : "Pending Invoices",
      "info" : "28 Days Left",
      "infoState" : "Success"
    }]

            }, {
                "type": "02",
                "typeKey": "1",
                 "TileCollection" : [
    {
      "id-tile": "3AP",
      "icon" : "sap-icon://inbox",
      "number" : "899999",
      "title" : "MERCHPAY IDOCs",
      "info" : "Overdue",
      "infoState" : "Error",
       "press" :  "sayAlert"
    },
    {
     "id-tile": "4AP",
      "type" : "sap-icon://Create",
       "number" : "57899",
      "title" : "Pending Invoices",
      "info" : "28 Days Left",
      "infoState" : "Success"
    }]
               }]
```

Comment: Did you try doing binding programmatically?

Comment: You wrote "but I want to make it dynamic from controller like myModel1>/n/TileCollection like n can be an 0 to 1000." - what does it mean?
I suggest to bind the "page" to needed path (in the controller): 
oPage.bindObject({path: "/n", model: "myModel"});
And then do your "tiles" binding relatively (in the view): tiles="myModel>TileCollection"

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But It is not working. Could you please let me know as to how you defined oPage ?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/bhNGXx?p=preview

Comment: Hi Andrii- I really appreciate the solution. I am sure it will help many to understand the binding concept.  But the page you have done binding is in a view. I am trying to bind a page that is in a fragment.  I would be great if you have any suggestion or solution for fragment....Thanks again....

Comment: No difference except retrieving controls from fragment. Plunk updated: https://plnkr.co/edit/bhNGXx?p=preview

Comment: Thank you.... Your solution works.... Really appreciate the help....